# Walk an UInt8 integer array in Swift; perform computation on subset of array

Tags: arrays, swift, reduce

I've got an array of unsigned integers and I'd like to get a product of certain subsets.

For example, if my array was [2,2,1,5], I'd like the product of every two numbers (2 * 2 = 4 and 1 * 5 = 5).

So far, I've got:

```
var myArray:[UInt8] = [2,2,1,5]
var mySlice: Array<UInt8>

for (index,i) in enumerate(myArray) {
    if (index % 2 == 1) {
        mySlice = Array(myArray[(index - 1)...index])
        println(mySlice.reduce(1,*))
        mySlice.removeAll()
    }
}
```

This seems like it would work (though ugly) but I get Execution was interrupted, reason: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION.

What's the best way to walk linearly down an array returning products (or computations) at certain intervals?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the problem is clearing out the slice while iterating the bigger array.

You should be able to work through this by adding the items to a separate array as you go, like this:

```
let myArray:[UInt8] = [2,2,1,5]
var result:[UInt8] = []

for (index,i) in enumerate(myArray) {
    if (index % 2 == 1) {
        let mySlice = Array(myArray[(index - 1)...index])
        let tmp = mySlice.reduce(1,*)
        result.append(tmp)
        println(tmp)
    }
}
println(result)
```

If you would like to put the results back into `myArray`, you can assign it after the loop.

[Demo.](http://www.runswiftlang.com/s/LYDneDR4)

Comment: Thanks for the website, pretty cool. And btw, you should probably make `myArray` a constant.

Comment: @DCMaxxx Yes, making `myArray` a constant makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, helpful with the lets.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few changes you can make that will make this much easier (and have much better performance) than your current attempt. First, use the global `stride(from:to:interval:)` function, which builds a sequence of indexes like the one you want -- no need to loop through all and skip the odd ones!

```
for i in stride(from: 0, to: myArray.count, by: 2) {
    // ...
}
```

Second, you can use a slice's `reduce` method, so you don't have to convert a Slice back to an Array (doing so is [unnecessary and inefficient](http://natecook.com/blog/2014/09/slicing-for-speed)):

```
let r = myArray[i ... i + 1].reduce(1, *)
```

So to bring it all together, your code could be:

```
var myArray: [UInt8] = [2, 2, 1, 5]
var result: [UInt8] = []

for i in stride(from: 0, to: myArray.count, by: 2) {
    result.append( myArray[i...i + 1].reduce(1, *) )
}
// result is [4, 5]
```